# How do I log some string on server and give it back to component as props using Next.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I apologize for a silly question, but I'm a newbie in Next.js, and I was given a task to "Add `"Hello from SSR"` string to a server log and give it back to `MyWonderfulComponent`", any ideas on how to do this?

**This is the code example**

```
export default function Page(props) {
    return <MyWonderfulComponent props={props}>I'm text from a component</MyWonderfulComponent>
}

function MyWonderfulComponent({ id, options, children, other }) {

    const [summ, setSumm] = useState(other);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (id && options) {
            setSumm(summ + 1);
        }
    }, [id, options]);

    console.log(summ);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <h1>Hello World!</h1>
            <Grid>
                <Grid xs={12}>{children}</Grid>
            </Grid>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Comment: Probably need something like cors to link your frontend and backend. Depending on your code structure

Comment: @JorgeGuerreiro it's Next.js, no need for CORS because the app is serving itself.

Comment: Can you post any more specifics about the requirements and anything you've tried so far?

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I think it might be just Next.js. I'm gonna edit the post in a minute to show an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest creating the "Hello from SSR" string in [getStaticProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation), one of the functions you can set on your components which will be called on the server-side.

From [the Next.js docs on data-fetching](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching):

> We’ll talk about the three unique Next.js functions you can use to
> fetch data for pre-rendering:
>
> - [getStaticProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation) (Static Generation): Fetch data at build time.
> - [getStaticPaths](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticpaths-static-generation) (Static Generation): Specify dynamic routes to
>   pre-render based on data.
> - [getServerSideProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering) (Server-side Rendering):
>   Fetch data on each request. In addition, we’ll talk briefly about how
>   to fetch data on the client side.

Untested, but did you try something like this?

```js
export async function getStaticProps (context) {
  const str = 'Hello from SSR'
  console.log(str) // log on the server-side
  return {
    props: { str } // will be passed to the page component as props
  }
}
```